# Add a custom id in textarea

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I need to add an ID into a `textarea` of body field on my custom "node-form.tpl.php". Now this body field will be rendered like this:

```
<textarea class="text-full form-textarea" id="edit-body-und-0-value" name="body[und][0][value]" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
```

I want to add a ID `redHat` into the texarea, that output should be:

```
<textarea class="text-full form-textarea" id="edit-body-und-0-value redHat" name="body[und][0][value]" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
```

To do this i have used `hook_form_alter()` in my `template.php` with no luck!

```
function bartik_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ) {
if($form_id == "article_node_form"){
    $form['body']['und']['0']['value']['#attributes']['#id'][] = 'redHat';
}
}
```

what i am missing? Thanks

Comment: Well, that seems to be a good idea, but i don't want JS for this,, Thanks

Comment: I dont think you can have more than 1 ID for an element. why dont you use class instead?

Comment: you ***definitely can not*** have multiple ids per tag

Comment: I need to add this ID to configure a **wysiwyg editor**

Comment: does the wysiwyg need an ID? if yes then why dont you use the default ID?

Answer (score 1):

Each element should have only one ID and it should be unique. You can change the body texarea `id` with the `hook_form_alter()`

**Example**

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if (isset($form['#node']) && $form['#node']->type == 'article') {
    // body textarea ID 
    $form['body']['und']['0']['#attributes']['id'] = 'redHat';
  }
}
```

but you cannot add the next one.